# How can you sync "learned spellings" between Macs

Tags: dictionary

OSX always tries to autocorrect the the unix commands that I save into my note taking application.

To prevent this, I right click and tell OSX to "Learn Spelling".

Is there a way to teach this spelling to all my Mac's? Ideally using iCloud or dropbox.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The spellings are located in various files in `~/Library/Spelling`.** Namely, LocalDictionary and various localisation files such as en_GB. You can sync this entire folder using a sync method of your choice.

- To sync via iCloud, symlink the folder to/from a folder in `~/Library/Mobile Documents`.
- To sync via Dropbox, symlink the folder to/from a folder in your Dropbox.